# How to prevent mod_rewrite from accepting a mistyped url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Firstly, I viewed [mod_rewrite - how to redirect a mistyped 'pretty' url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190661/) however the OP is wanting his mistyped URL's to redirect to the correct, I simply want mine to error404.

quick question. I am looking for a solution to improve upon some mod re_write code I have.

Currently if someone was to enter an URL on my site that was a product page I.e. "/products/[category]/[product-name]" the .htaccess file has the following code

```
RewriteRule ^products\/([^/]+)\/([^/]+)$        ?page=product&product=$2 [L]
```

Which works exactly as intended however if someone mistyped only the [product-name] the template page still loads using that product-name in the URL as a variable and not landing a 404 error.

I handle all error pages like thus:

```
#ErrorDocument 404          /index.php?page=error404
```

Hoping someone can shine a light on how to adapt the former rewrite rule so pages that don't exist I.e. if we had a product called kettle and someone typed in ketle at the end of the URL it would 404 rather than still load the template page with ketle as the GET var.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can even write a PHP script into the *<head>* element of your dynamic page, with this format as an example:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("$hostname", "$username", "$password", "$database");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT content FROM pages WHERE id = $value LIMIT 1");

if (0 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<meta http-equiv="location" content="URL=http://www.yourdomain.com/index.php?page=error404">';
}
```

Note: double check the code above if it's right, for it's just an example, and didn't reviewed well the syntax and if *mysqli_fetch_array()* is used to count the row*(s)* on the *$result* of the SQL queries.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you're `index.php` script handles the "page" and "product" parameters. It's going to be the only one that's going to know whether the "product" parameter actually points to a valid product name or not. If not, then you need to use the [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function to generate the 404, and then display the contents of `page=error404`.

The htaccess file and mod_rewrite isn't going to know whether a page name is correct or mistyped, only the script that does the lookup will know.